# Remove character from column of CSV

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a file similar to the following:

```
random,test123,MyCompany, Inc.
hello,12345,TestCompany, LLC
```

I want to remove the commas from the third column so I'd have something like this:

```
random,test123,MyCompany Inc.
hello,12345,TestCompany LLC
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You mean third occurrences of comma?

Comment: If the first two "columns" contain a comma somewhere, then both answers below (and any others that are general enough to be useful) will fail. If that's the case, then you will have to do some manual editing. Otherwise, either answer works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy with sed:

```
sed 's/,//3' file
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUG9WF9HX99Y/f//osS8lPxcnZLU4hJDI2Md30rn/NyCxLxKHQXPvGQ9rozUnJx8HaCMialOCFANXNbHxxkA)

If you want to directly apply the modifications in your input file, then run:

```
sed -i 's/,//3' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With **awk**:

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3$4}' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
random,test123,MyCompany Inc.
hello,12345,TestCompany LLC
```